# scrollview with listview not working

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I've only included one direct child in the scroll view , and i've added the below codes in the java files. When i remove the Utility method the listview appear fully, but doesnt work as a scrollview

```
        ScrollView sv_fragment_globe;
        sv_fragment_globe = (ScrollView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.sv_fragment_globe);
        sv_fragment_globe.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
        Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(holder.lv_globe);
```

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sv_fragment_globe"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_hospital1"
                android:id="@+id/iv_vp_globe"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />


            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lv_globe"
                >


            </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>



</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Nesting scrollable Views is an anti-pattern. You'll most likely end up with scroll-fighting problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/home_hospital"
            android:id="@+id/iv_vp_globe"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lv_globe"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >


        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: entire list view came out nicely, but scroll view doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than two scrolling views inside any Layout, then the parent scrolling view will only scrolls. Follow the steps below to allows the child's scrolling elements to scroll.

Step 1:
Create a custom ListView.

public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
{

```
boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded()
{
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
{
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
```

}

Step 2: Add the line below after initializing the Listview object.

lv_selected_time_zone.setExpanded(true);